# Are questions about core magento features off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I want to know more about the differences between Community and Enterprise, specifically what features are included in the core functionality that we wouldn't need extensions to do.  Is this type of question off-topic?

To be clear, I am not looking for an itemized list of features, but specifics.  For instance, with our current Community installation, we have an extension called "Multi Warehouse" that provides functionality to adjust multiple inventories, split orders based on which warehouse the items will ship from, calculate different shipping for each split order, etc.  But this extension is causing some difficulties with other extensions, and even with some of the core functionality (very subtle stuff, but tested and confirmed).

So my proposed question would be something like: "What functionality does Enterprise offer to deal with multiple inventories and shipping centers?"

I am not looking for the answer here, just whether this would be on-topic for the Magento Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

No, these types of questions are absolutely valid.

And no, EE is not providing functionality for managing multiple stocks.